# Not separable first order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a two part question on first order DEs

i) Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $y=ux$ where $u$ is a function of $x$

ii) Hence solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2}{2x^2}+\frac12$ given $y(1)=2$

For i) I got $\frac{dy}{dx}=u+u'x$
$=\frac{y}{x}+x\frac{x\frac{dy}{dx}-y}{x^2}$
But this then simplifies down to $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}$ so I'm unsure whether I should just leave the answer as $\frac{dy}{dx}=u+u'x$

For ii) I got no ideas, I've tried guessing random substitutions for $u$ such as $x+\frac12$ but I have had no luck.

Can someone please show me how to use part i to solve ii?

Comment: For (ii) lets try the substitution in(i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**...When you substitute the expression you have for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ into the given differential equation, and substitute for $\frac yx=u$, you get
$$u+x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac12u^2+\frac12$$
$$\implies x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac12(u-1)^2$$

can you continue?